# @mention's don't work in Universal Action Model response

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an AdaptiveCard that includes a mention and has an `Action.Execute` button. When I post this message to a chat/conversation, the mention works and the user's name is a link to their profile.

When the user clicks the button, it fires off an `invoke` action to my API. I'm responding with the exact same AdaptiveCard, yet the mention is no longer a link and is not formatted.

The initial message which uses the [Send to conversation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-to-conversation) has this structure:

```rb
adaptive_card = [
  {
    "contentType" => "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content" => {
      "type" => "AdaptiveCard",
      "$schema" => "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version" => "1.4",
      "body" => [
        {
          "type" => "TextBlock",
          "text" => "Have you met, <at>Hunter Meyer</at>?"
        },
        {
          "type" => "ActionSet",
          "actions" => [
            {
              "type" => "Action.Execute",
              "verb" => "met_reply",
              "title" => "Yes",
              "data" => {
                "response" => "yes"
              }
            },
            {
              "type" => "Action.Execute",
              "verb" => "met_reply",
              "title" => "No",
              "data" => {
                "response" => "no"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "msteams" => {
        "entities" => [
          {
            "type" => "mention",
            "text" => "<at>Hunter Meyer</at>",
            "mentioned" => {
              "name" => "Hunter Meyer",
              "id" => "<redacted-user-azure-ad-id>"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm following the [Universal Action Model response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/universal-action-model#response-format) to render a card in place of the other. This is the response. Notice the `value` is the `adaptive_card["content"]` from above.

```rb
{
  statusCode: 200,
  type: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
  value: adaptive_card["content"]
}
```

Everything works except the user's name is no longer treated as a mention. It's the raw `<at>Hunter Meyer</at>`.

[image: borked_mention_experience]

Comment: Yes, you are right, using universal action adaptive card, @mention is not working once the card gets updated.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!